# how to transform the following in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following model

```
public class Node
    {
        public int AutoIncrementId { get; set; }


        public string Text { get; set; }


        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

          ...//other propeties

     }
```

I want to transform the data into the following model,

```
public class TreeView
{    
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Text {get; set;}
 public List<TreeView> Items {get; set;}    
}
```

I started with the following, but then realised how am I going to know when to stop?

the variable test holds the node data

```
var items = test.Data.Select(x => new TreeViewItemModel
   {
     Id = x.AutoIncrementId.ToString(),
     Text = x.Text,
     Items =   x.Nodes.Select(y=> new TreeViewItemModel(
     {

       Id =  y.AutoIncrementId.ToString(),
       Text =  y.Text,
       Items = //do I keep going? 

     }));    
  }    
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `TreeView` hold a `List<Node> Items` instead of `List<TreeView> Items`?

Comment: commusoft - no Treeview holds List<Treeview>

Comment: mcl - can you show me an example or code snippet of recursion for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity and simplicity, this works nicely:

```
public TreeView ConvertNode(Node rootNode)
{
    var tree = new TreeView
    {
        Id = rootNode.AutoIncrementId,
        Text = rootNode.Text,
        Items = new List<TreeView>()
    };

    if (rootNode.Nodes != null)
    {
        foreach (var node in rootNode.Nodes)
        {
            tree.Items.Add(ConvertNode(node));
        }
    }

    return tree;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to do that:

```
public TreeView ConvertToTreeView(Node node)
{
    TreeView tv = new TreeView();

    tv.Id = node.AutoIncrementId;
    tv.Text = node.Text;
    if (node.Nodes != null && node.Nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        tv.Items = new List<TreeView>();
        node.Nodes.ForEach(x => tv.Items.Add(ConvertToTreeView(x)));
    }

    return tv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this form.

```
public TreeView ConvertToTreeView(Node node)
{
    return new TreeView
            {

                Id = node.AutoIncrementId;
                Text = node.Text;
                Items = node.Nodes.Select(ConvertToTreeView).ToList()
            };
}
```

Edit: Yes Baldrick, I did :P and

```
public TreeView ConvertToTreeView(Node node)
{
    return new TreeView
            {

                Id = node.AutoIncrementId;
                Text = node.Text;
                Items = node.Nodes != null
                           ? node.Nodes.Select(ConvertToTreeView).ToList()
                           : new List<TreeView>()
            };
}
```

Just doesn't look as nice.

Comment: Don't you mean `Node.Nodes.Select` - and won't that crash if 'Nodes' is null?

Comment: @Aron: It might not *look* as nice, but then a 'object reference' error message doesn't look very nice either...